# Array variable is not getting set - PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, isset

I am trying to set array, but it is not getting set. Everytime the *Buy* function called, the array gets declared.

This is the function is controller.

```
public function buy() {
    if($this->session->userdata('counter')){
        $counter = $this->session->userdata('counter');
        $this->session->set_userdata('counter', $counter + 1);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('counter', 1);

    }
if(isset($bought)){
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $price = $this->input->post('price');
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
        $product = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $price, 'qty'=> $qty);
        array_push($bought, $product);
        var_dump($bought);
        die();
    } else {
        $bought = array();

    redirect("");
    }
```

As you can see, it should remember that *$bought* is set, but it gets declared anew. For now I

- tried to make it global, before "public function __construct()",
- tried "if (!empty),
- tried to put into session,
- tried to find the answer across whole stackoverflow...

Please let me know if additional info needed.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you set the session library in constructor of controller??

Comment: $this->load->library('session'); under you controller consrtustor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when you are checking for `$bought`, it is not present so it is going to the `else` part everytime. Instead define a `blank array` and then set the values inside it.  Try with -

```
if(isset($_SESSION['bought'])){
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $price = $this->input->post('price');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $product = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $price, 'qty'=> $qty);
    array_push($_SESSION['bought'], $product);
    var_dump($_SESSION['bought']);
    die();
} else {
    $_SESSION['bought'] = array();
}
```

And start the session at top of the page.

Comment: Tried this, but it gets declared again anew and always keeps only one value, the one just set.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then I will pass everything to cart.

Comment: Updated the answer.. Use session for this.

Comment: Since this is Codeigniter, I guess I will have to use $this->session->userdata... I will try, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77152/discussion-between-nurgul-alshyn-and-sgt-bose).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

I made a workaround with sgt's help, so now my code looks like this:

```
if($this->session->userdata('bought')){
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $price = $this->input->post('price');
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
        $product = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $price, 'qty'=> $qty);

        // please see that here I just returned from old one and added new data to the old one. 
        // Then I just added the result to the session.
        $old_session =  $this->session->userdata('bought');
        array_push($old_session, $product);
        $this->session->set_userdata('bought', $old_session);

        redirect("");
    } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('bought', array());
}
```